# How to separate Column string by ; and assign row value in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have an example dataframe

```
df = data.frame(day = c("Monday", "Tuesday; Wednesday", "Thursday"),
                      c(2, 3, 5))
```

I want to separate all strings with "; " and assign the value of the second column like this:

```
      df_goal = data.frame(value= c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday"),
                           c(2, 3, 3, 5))
```

My original data is much larger so I am looking for larger scale applicable solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `separate_rows`, by default, the default separator is punctuation signs; but you can manually indicate it using `sep = "; "`

```r
library(tidyr)
separate_rows(df, day)
#separate_rows(df, day, sep = "; ")
```

output

```r
  day       c.2..3..5.
  <chr>          <dbl>
1 Monday             2
2 Tuesday            3
3 Wednesday          3
4 Thursday           5
```

Comment: how do I add the separation condition "; " ?

Comment: Use `sep = "; "`

Comment: inside the separate rows? like separate_rows(df, day, sep = "; ") ?

Comment: Yep; see the answer.